# how to write a function that takes 2 strings, and add them to the BEGINNING of the respective arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have this problem where I need to write a function that accepts and author and title. Add an author to the beginning of the authors array and one at the beginning of the titles array, using an array method. Make sure you invoke the function to actually add the 2 items to the 2 respective arrays. In a loop, list in console.log the list of authors and their titles. Hint: function addToArrays(myAuthor, myTitle){ ... }.

I know the simple way to get it to work properly is like this.

```
let authors = ['Ernest Hemingway', 'Charlotte Bronte', 'Louisa May Alcott', 'Charles Dickens'];

let titles = ['The Old Man and the Sea', 'Jane Eyre', 'Little Women', 'Oliver Twist'];

myAuthor = authors.unshift("Stephen King");
myTitle = titles.unshift("Tommyknockers");
console.log(authors, titles);
```

It gives the results the proper way that I need them. However for the life of my I can not seem to figure out how to put it into a function to do as the question is asking. I am very frustrated and feel very stupid not being able to figure it out. I have tried a number of different methods.

```
let authors = ['Ernest Hemingway', 'Charlotte Bronte', 'Louisa May Alcott', 'Charles Dickens'];

let titles = ['The Old Man and the Sea', 'Jane Eyre', 'Little Women', 'Oliver Twist'];

function addToArrays(myAuthor, myTitle) {
    let myAuthor = authors;
    let myTitle = titles;
    for (let i = 0; i < authors.length; i++){
        authors.unshift("Stephen King");
        for (let j = 0; i < titles.length; i++){
            titles.unshift("Tommyknockers");
        }
        return titles;
    }
    return authors;
    console.log(authors, titles);
}
console.log(addToArrays);
```

or

```
let authors = ['Ernest Hemingway', 'Charlotte Bronte', 'Louisa May Alcott', 'Charles Dickens'];

let titles = ['The Old Man and the Sea', 'Jane Eyre', 'Little Women', 'Oliver Twist'];

function addToArrays(myAuthor, myTitle) {
    let myAuthor = authors;
    let myTitle = titles;
    authors.unshift("Stephen King");
    titles.unshift("Tommyknockers");
    return titles;
    return authors;
    console.log(authors, titles);
}
```

I am just not sure where I am going wrong. I am sure it is something simple that I am doing wrong it not knowing what I am doing is making me feel like rage quitting. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have a number of problems.  For one you're overwriting the input parameters to your function.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be what I always do when put under pressure for these types of things. I overwrite and overthink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you should just wrap your unshift calls in a function. Simply like this:

```
function addToArrays(myAuthor, myTitle) {
  authors.unshift(myAuthor);
  titles.unshift(myTitle);
}

addToArrays('author', 'title');
console.log(authors, titles);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That is exactly what I needed. I am almost always overthinking what needs to be done to make something work properly and as a result I can never get to the correct answer which I should have known to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close with your second attempt, edited to work below (with explanation):

```js
const authors = ['Ernest Hemingway', 'Charlotte Bronte', 'Louisa May Alcott', 'Charles Dickens'];

const titles = ['The Old Man and the Sea', 'Jane Eyre', 'Little Women', 'Oliver Twist'];

function addToArrays(myAuthor, myTitle) {
    // let myAuthor = authors; // myAuthor is already a parameter, no need to redeclare it here
    // let myTitle = titles; // same for myTitle
    authors.unshift(myAuthor); // use 'Stephen King' that was passed into the function as myAuthor rather than hardcoding it
    titles.unshift(myTitle); // same for 'Tommyknockers'
    // return titles; // return should be placed at the end of the function (only one)
    // return authors; // multiple returns won't work
    console.log(authors, titles); // anything after a return statement is unreachable, that's why you didn't see your console.log earlier
    // when there's no return value in a function it implicitly returns undefined so you can imagine here: `return undefined;` but it's not needed
}

addToArrays('Stephen King', 'Tommyknockers'); // don't forget to actually call the function!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let authors = ['Ernest Hemingway', 'Charlotte Bronte', 'Louisa May Alcott', 'Charles Dickens'];
let titles = ['The Old Man and the Sea', 'Jane Eyre', 'Little Women', 'Oliver Twist'];
function addToArrays(myAuthor, myTitle,authors,titles) {
Authors=authors.unshift(myAuthor); //add the first parameter to the 3rd parameter which is authors array
Titles=titles.unshift(myTitle); // add second parameter to 4th parameter which is title array
let returned={ // create object which hold authors and titles 
Authors:authors,
Titles:titles
}
return returned; // return this obj from the function
}
console.log(addToArrays('Stephen   King','Tommyknockers',authors,titles)); // to print the hole object
    console.log(addToArrays('Stephen   King','Tommyknockers',authors,titles).Authors); // to print the authors 
    console.log(addToArrays('Stephen   King','Tommyknockers',authors,titles).Titles); // to print the titles
```